# Are there any way to create query from sql query to entity object query in jpa

Tags: jpa

I have a query like the one shown below:

```
SELECT
  SUM (LIMIT_AMOUNT)
FROM
  (SELECT
    CTR_NO
    , REPORT_DATE
    , LIMIT_AMOUNT
    , ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (PARTITION BY CTR_NO, REPORT_DATE ORDER BY REPORT_DATE) rn
  FROM LOD_CONTRACT
  WHERE
    br_cst_code='3432434'
  AND REPORT_DATE BETWEEN '20-FEB-15' AND '28-FEB-15') b
WHERE
  b.rn=1;
```

How can I build a SQL query for a JPA-managed entity like:

```
SELECT
  SUM (o.limit_amount)
FROM
  (SELECT
    o.ctr_no
    , o.rpt_dt
    , o.limit_amount
    , ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (PARTITION BY o.ctr_no, o.rpt_dt ORDER BY o.rpt_dt) rn
  FROM LOD_CONTRACT o
  WHERE
    o.br_cst_code='3432434'
  AND o.rpt_dt BETWEEN '20-FEB-15' AND '28-FEB-15') b
WHERE
  b.rn=1;
```

Comment: Your query is correct.  What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: do you mean "how can i create a JPQL query equivalent to this SQL query?" If that is the case, then you can't ... you can't have a SUBQUERY in the select clause, you can't have OVER keyword. That should be evident from looking at any half decent JPQL docs

Answer (score 1):

JPQL doesn't currently support Oracle partition tables. To use this feature you will have to stick to Native queries.